# .tmLanguage file for LaTeX: what are the online resources?

Tags: textmate, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a `.tmLanguage` file defining the syntax of `LaTeX`. I have looked [there](https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle) but can't find it.

Where can I find (good) `.tmLanguage` files for LaTeX?

---

PS: I found a file on the web but [I encounter problems with it](https://github.com/soffes/SyntaxKit/issues/19) and wonder if the syntax is ok.

Comment: Now charged 30€, with no documentation. No, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The syntax is defined in https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/LaTeX.plist

Comment: I try to use the `.tm` file to develop a `GUI` for typing LaTeX. I encounter this issue, if you can by any chance help: https://github.com/soffes/SyntaxKit/issues/19

Comment: @egreg Are you talking of the software `textmate`? Or the file for the syntax?

Comment: @Colas I was thinking to TextMate, yes. An attempt at a free version is welcome, but every time I tried to make a sense of those files, I got lost.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell I've also just looked at the code of TexShop but was not able to identify the place where the syntax highlighting is done.

Comment: @egreg There is [an open-source project](https://github.com/soffes/SyntaxKit) whose goal is to make sense of these files. I've just found [an issue with the latex syntax](https://github.com/soffes/SyntaxKit/issues/19#issuecomment-269303397). Feel free to have a look ;-)

Comment: You can look in `TSDocument-Syntax.m` to see what TeXShop does for syntax highlighting.